# DataGrid with binding for rows and just some columns?

Tags: xaml, templates, binding, datagrid

[image]

How do I get a datagrid like this with templates for rows as well as for repeatable cells?

DataGrid is bound to a property called Blocks, which is a BindingList of Block type, defined in the view model:

```
                        <DataGrid x:Name="dgBlocks" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                              Margin="20,10,10,20" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Blocks, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                              CanUserAddRows="False"
                              SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Single"
                              EnableColumnVirtualization="False"
                              EnableRowVirtualization="False"
                              SelectedIndex="-1" MinRowHeight="10"                            
                              LoadingRow="dg_LoadingRow" 
                              SelectionChanged="dgBlocks_SelectionChanged"
                              >

                            <DataGrid.Resources>
                                <helper:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />

                                <!--todo: change to symbol’s ‘ReadOnly’ property instead of block’s ‘Permission’ -->

                                <Style x:Key="CellPermissionStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Permission, Converter={StaticResource BlockPermissionToBrushConverter}}" />
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Permission, Converter={StaticResource BlockPermissionToBoolConverter}}" />
                                </Style>


                            </DataGrid.Resources>
                            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Name="txtBlockRowHeader"
                                               Text="{Binding Path=Header,
                                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}">
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                    <!-- Selection checkboxes -->
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsThreeState="True" ToolTip="Select All" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                                <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                                                    <Binding Path="DataContext.SelectAll" 
                                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"
                                                             Mode="TwoWay"
                                                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                                                             />
                                                </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                                            </CheckBox>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox Margin="5,0,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                        <TextBlock Text="Repeat" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <telerik:RadNumericUpDown Name="nudRepeatBlock" ValueFormat="Numeric" Width="40"
                                                      ToolTip="Repeat block number of times" IsInteger="True" IsEditable="True"
                                                      Minimum="1" Maximum="100" UpdateValueEvent="PropertyChanged"
                                                      Value="{Binding Repeat, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="40" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False"
                                                Visibility="{Binding Data.Encoding, Converter={StaticResource Encoding8b10bToCollapsedConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}">
                                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"  Value="Center" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                </DataGridTextColumn>

                                <!--todo: change… -->
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="[0]" Binding="{Binding .Symbols[0].SymbolText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellPermissionStyle}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="[1]" Binding="{Binding .Symbols[1].SymbolText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellPermissionStyle}" />
                                <!-- … -->
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="[15]" Binding="{Binding .Symbols[15].SymbolText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellPermissionStyle}" />


                            </DataGrid.Columns>

                        </DataGrid>
```

Each Block object has a property called Symbols, defined as a BindingList of Symbol type, and **some other properties**.  Symbols get shown in columns with headers [0], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTval.jpg), etc.
Other block’s properties shown in other columns.  E.g. IsSelected for checkbox, Reapeat, Name.

```
    public interface ISymbol
    {
        int Index { get; set; }
        bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
        string SymbolText { get; set; }
    }

    public class BlockBase : ObservableObject, IDataErrorInfo
    {

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set 
            {
                if (value == _isSelected)
                    return;

                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                RaiseSelectionChangedEvent();
            }
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual BindingList<ISymbol> Symbols { get; set; }
        public BlockPermission Permission { get; set; }

        public int Repeat { get; set; }

    }


    public class Symbol : ObservableObject, ISymbol
    {
        DisplayFormat Format { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public virtual bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
        public virtual string SymbolText
        {
            get { return (Format == DisplayFormat.Binary) ? _binSymbol : _hexSymbol; 
        }
        set
        {
            // …  validate and set _binSymbol & _hexSymbol values
            OnPropertyChanged("SymbolText");
        }
    }
```

Now, I need to bind each symbol’s cell 'IsEnabled' property to Symbol's 'ReadOnly' property.
I tried to define this in DataGrid.Resources as CellPermissionStyle, but I don’t know how to access a Symbol on this level.

Also, it would be nice to replace all repeating DataGridTextColumn defenitions for symbols with a template.

Would somebody help me?

Comment: Can you please show the entire DataGrid from your xaml, and the Block definition code?

Comment: @Mishka, I've edited my question with info you've requested.  Thanks

Comment: In your cell style, its currently binded to Permission, not to ReadoOnly.
I think, since you use a converter anyway, you can just bind to 'empty' meaning the Block. and in the converter get its Symbols, and check.
To know in which column you are you can can pass a ConverterParameter in the binding. It will be the number(you will need several styles, one for each column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My researches just confirmed that unfortunately there is no way to do this with templates or styles applicable to a subset of columns.  It is also imposible to send a parameter to a style or template as Mishka suggested :(.

So, I've just ended up with 'copy-paste-modify' cell style for each of my 16 columns like that:

```
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="[0]" Binding="{Binding .Symbols[0].SymbolText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">                                        
                                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding .Symbols[0].ReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource SymbolReadOnlyToBrushConverter}}" />
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding .Symbols[0].ReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource SymbolReadOnlyToEnabledConverter}}" />
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

...

```
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="[15]" Binding="{Binding .Symbols[15].SymbolText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
                                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding .Symbols[15].ReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource SymbolReadOnlyToBrushConverter}}" />
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding .Symbols[15].ReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource SymbolReadOnlyToEnabledConverter}}" />
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Yes, I know, this XAML looks ugly, but it works for me without a risky redesign of existing code base.

I'd be happy if someone could suggest a better, more elegant way doing this in XAML.